# JS Callback called from an ActiveX component not triggering if not in the main code flow

Tags: javascript, c#, callback, activex, dom-events

I have an ActiveX component which scans the photo, saves the file into a temp file on the client's hard drive and uploads the photo.

I have a "TwainMan" instance that does the scanning part and which after scanning is done, triggers the "ImageScanned" event. This is my main code flow:

```
scanner = new TwainMan();
scanner.ImageScanned += new ImageScannedEventHandler(Scanner_ImageScanned);
```

The code that does that is placed into the EventHandler delegate method "Scanner_ImageScanned":

```
private void Scanner_ImageScanned(object Sender, ImageScannedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tempFileName = scanner.ToTempFile(e.Image);
    MessageBox.Show("Scanned picture stored on the following location:\n" + this.tempFileName);

    Upload(this.tempFileName); // works just fine

    TriggerJSCallback(); // here is where the problem appears!           
}
```

In the TriggerJSCallback method I only trigger my JS Callback:

```
private void TriggerJSCallback()
{
    EventHandler DataPreparingFinished = this.DataPreparingFinished;
    if (null != DataPreparingFinished) { DataPreparingFinished(this.tempFileName); }
}
```

Note that if I trigger the JSCallback "DataPreparingFinished" from within the main flow, the JS Callback listener (defined in my html page) works just fine, but the problem appears if the trigger "DataPreparingFinished" is triggered from within the "Scanner_ImageScanned" delegate, thus not from the main code flow.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Here's the JS Callback definition within the html page, inside the  tag.

```
<script for="AXTwain" event="DataPreparingFinished(args)" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function AXTwain::DataPreparingFinished(args) {            
        alert("JS ALERT: SUCCESS!!! JS Callback working properly." + args);
        // alert("The temp file is stored on: " + AXTwain.TempFileName); 
    }

</script>
```

---

Maybe it would be good if I'd show more code, so you would get a better idea of what my problem actually is.

Let's go from the top...

Below is my HTML page which includes my ActiveXObject instantiatin and the JS callback / listener function.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>ActiveX TWAIN test page</title>

    <object id="AXTwain" name="AXTwain" classid="clsid:d8ea830e-38b0-4f3b-8be4-39c417c27583"></object>

</head>

<body onload="myload();">

    <h1 style="color:green;">AXTwain test page</h1> 

    <script type ="text/javascript">

        function myload() {
            if (AXTwain != null) {
                AXTwain.AcquireImage();
            }           
        }

    </script>

    <script for="AXTwain" event="DataPreparingFinished(args)" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        // The "for" attribute should be set to the name of instance of your COM component.
        // The "event" attribute should be set to the JavaScript function signature for the event.
        // The name of the JavaScript function is the instance name of your COM component, followed
        // by double colons, followed by the JavaScript signature of the event.

        function AXTwain::DataPreparingFinished(args) {            
            alert("JS ALERT: SUCCESS!!! JS Callback working properly." + args);            
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my my ActiveX wrapper class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AXImageAcquisition
{
    #region ActiveX attributes
    [ProgId("AXImageAcquisition.AXTwain_01")]
    [Guid("d8ea830e-38b0-4f3b-8be4-39c417c27583")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComEvents))]
    #endregion
    public class AXTwain
    {
        #region Class Properties and Settings

        private TwainMan scanner;
        private String tempFileName;
        public String TempFileName
        {
            get { return this.tempFileName; }
        }

        [ComVisible(false)]
        public delegate void EventHandler(string args);
        public event EventHandler DataPreparingFinished;

        public bool imageScanned = false;

        #endregion

        #region Class Constructors
        public AXTwain()
        {}
        #endregion

        #region Class Methods

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void AcquireImage()
        {
            this.DataPreparingFinished += new EventHandler(Delegate_DataPreparingFinished);

            this.scanner = new TwainMan();
            this.scanner.ImageScanned += new ImageScannedEventHandler(Scanner_ImageScanned);            

            TriggerJSCallback(); // HERE IN THE MAIN CODE FLOW THE MESSAGE GETS TO JS!!!
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate that defines functionality for the ImageScanned event, defined in TwainMan class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void Scanner_ImageScanned(object Sender, ImageScannedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.tempFileName = scanner.ToTempFile(e.Image);
            Upload(this.tempFileName);            

            TriggerJSCallback(); // HERE (NOT IN THE MAIN CODE FLOW) THE MESSAGE NEVER GETS TO JS!!! WHYYYY? :(
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TODO!!!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tempFileName"></param>
        private void Upload(string tempFileName)
        {
            // TODO
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Test method for the DataPreparingFinished trigger.
        /// </summary>
        public void TriggerJSCallback()
        {           
            EventHandler DataPreparingFinished = this.DataPreparingFinished;
            if (null != DataPreparingFinished) DataPreparingFinished(this.tempFileName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate that defines functionality for the DataPreparingFinished event, which is defined in IComEvents.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msg">Arguments passing from C# to JS.</param>
        void Delegate_DataPreparingFinished(string msg)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Delegate_DataPreparingFinished message! (C# code).\n Input message: " + msg);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In case you need more code, I can also copy/paste the rest of the code, that is the TwainMan class and it's dependancies. However all that is taken from a codeproject tutorial, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx?display=Mobile&fid=2619&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1958970&fr=341&prof=True). Btw, thanks to the author.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain since I don't write ActiveX components from C#, but in c++ a callback like that would have exactly that effect if called from a thread other than the main thread. ActiveX generally expects all calls to occur on the main thread. There are ways to make other threads work with ActiveX as well, though, and it's possible that C# does this for you automatically so this may not always be accurate in c#.

I would recommend that you find a way to trigger the function on the main thread; I know there are ways to do this in Silverlight using the DispatcherTimer; perhaps you can find something similar? Anyway, that's what I'd try.

Comment: Taxilian, thank you sincerely for your response. When I was mentioning the "code flow" I did not have in mind threads. So, when I say "main code flow", I do not mean the main thread. :) But maybe I used the wrong terminology. :)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that c# isn't using another thread without you realizing it? Anyway, that was my only idea, but I thought I'd throw it out there as an FYI. If there is a DispatcherTimer or something similar I'd try it just to be sure.  Either way, good luck

Comment: To be honest I was thinking the same thing and I am still not sure if there is another thread behind or not. IMHO there is not, cause I don't see any explixit thread start in the code available to me, but to be really sure I have to do some further research... find a way to find out that ASAP. But still, on the other hand... in another test code I tried triggering the event from a new thread and the JS Callback caught the event properly. What I need to do is to find a way to catch all the messages and see if my message actually triggers and where it gets lost.